# Android Firebase AppCheck startup time

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-app-check

I start to implement Android Firebase AppCheck in my application and it seems to make my app startup time much slower.

I initialize firebase and AppCheck in the onCreate of my Application classe as I saw on the documentation. My first displayed screen show a list of items reached from a Firestore collection. I can see a difference of 2 or 3 Seconds before showing content, after I implemented the app check initialization. Did someone experienced the same things ? I tested in debug and release and the slow start is the same.

Thanks for your time :)

Edit :

I init the code like that on my Application class :

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startUpTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
    val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
    firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
        PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
    )
}
```

Then I make a diff with the value store in "startUpTime" at the moment I display the first data in the RecyclerView.

When AppCheck is initialized the diff say something like 3000 milliseconds, and when I remove AppCheck I'm around 800 milliseconds.
Also it's pretty easy to feel and see when launching the application.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code of how you initialize app check, and how you measure the startup performance?

Comment: I added the info. Don't hesitate if you need more insight @AlexMamo

Comment: Can you try initializing it on your first Activity instead of your Application class? I'm just curious to see if it would make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your idea @RosárioPereiraFernandes. Sadly it gave the same result :(

Comment: @SamuelTerroitin I tried to reproduce your issue, but could not. Can you maybe create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a GitHub repo?

Comment: Im experiencing the same issue. It adds around 2 seconds of loading time. Seems like it's still not fixed.